# implementation of config method behind ipython

Tags: python, ipython, enthought

Based on this video tutorial
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2G5YTlheCbw#t=01h07m41s

The presenter mentions the method used to process the input config for iPython. I don't get which method he used. The only thing I can hear is "n thoughts trace machinery". Searched through google without results.

Can someone take one more listen and tell me what he means?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's saying "Enthought's Traits Machinery":

[Enthought](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php)

The
[free version](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php)
includes
[Traits](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/)

From @Matt's link:

Underneath the hood, the `Configurable` base class is a subclass of `IPython.utils.traitlets.HasTraits`. The `IPython.utils.traitlets` module is a lightweight version of `enthought.traits`. Our implementation is a pure Python subset (mostly API compatible) of `enthought.traits` that does not have any of the automatic GUI generation capabilities. Our plan is to achieve 100% API compatibility to enable the actual `enthought.traits` to eventually be used instead. Currently, we cannot use `enthought.traits` as we are committed to the core of IPython being pure Python.

Comment: To add on this, [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/overview.html) is the documentation for the IPython configuration system.